# Back button text will not change tint

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to change my back button text color for certain views. I can change the arrow color, but the text will not change tint. I have tried:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, NSFontAttributeName : font};

[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:dictionary forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have also tried:

```
NSString *backText = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title;
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backText style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, NSFontAttributeName : font};
[backButton setTitleTextAttributes:dictionary forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

I have a global tint set in Storyboard. It should override it though right?

How can i get the text to change?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the tint of the navigation bar?  In storyboard, go to the UINavigationController.  In the outline, select the Navigation Bar.  Then in the Attributes Inspector, change the Tint color (under the View section).  This changes the color of the default back button.

Comment: I just tried that and it does work, but I want to have a different back button text color for different screens in the same navigation stack. The arrow changes, but not the text.

Comment: In `viewWillAppear` do `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = <Insert UIColor>`;

Comment: Tried it and no use. I have tried everything I can think of. I am not setting the tint except for my global tint in storyboard, but this should override that.

Comment: If things are working okay in storyboard, but not when you make the change programmatically, there are few things to check. 1) The class of the `UIViewController` being shown when you go to Identity Inspector in storyboard should match your `UIViewController` subclass where you place the `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor` code. You can also set a breakpoint on this line and make sure this is being called. 2) Are you using a subclass of UINavigationController. This may have a `setTint` in itself that is causing trouble.  3) Are you using `[UINavigationBar appearance]` anywhere?

Comment: 4) Are you adding a UINavigationBar object anywhere?  Or are you solely using the default one that comes with UINavigationController?

Comment: I have tried creating a bar button item as mentioned, and I am not using [UINavigationBar appearance]. I am also not subclassing my NavigationController and my class is assigned correctly, as I am able to change the arrow color.

Comment: Oh that's your issue.  I think you're overwriting the default back button with one of your own.  Is there a reason why you need to add in a custom back button?  If not... just delete the barbuttonitem you created.

Comment: I have tired both ways and the color does not change.

Comment: sorry.. don't know what the reason is.

Comment: Yeah I am really stumped. Thanks for the help though. I am starting to think it is related to the global tint. it is somehow overriding all tint settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You can add that line under `AppDelegate.m` under `-(BOOL)application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions` in my case i'm using uinavigationcontroller programmatically for some reason..

so mine is looking something like this..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //..codes
     [self.navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];//fontColor
     //..codes
}
```

while in *storyboard* you may find it under **View > Utilities > Show attribute inspector > View > Tint**.. Change the color there and thats it..

**Hey! I tried your code!** :) and it works just fine for me..
i think you just misplaced your code...

dont place you code in the current viewcontrollers *-viewDidLoad*
add it in the viewcontroller before it..

something like this..
//firstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //place your code here..
}
```

and you'll see the effect at `//secondViewController.m`

Comment: I don't think you want to put it in viewDidLoad, since if you are moving back and forth between view controllers, you want to update the color each time a view appears.

Comment: Oh yes.. haha.. i just copy pasted by code from my project.. with different color per viewcontroller... i'll edit it.. :)

Comment: Yeah, it works when I put it in prepareForSegue. I wonder if there is a bug with the global tint color and inherited in the storyboard. I am trying to play with a few things.

Comment: Haha.. Okay, thats sounds fun to me.. Good luck with the playing though with the "few" things which is basically chained.. Curious minds are the best out there.. :) Have fun on what you are doing.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was placing this code in prepareForSegue of the previous class in the navigation stack.

```
NSString *backText = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title;
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backText style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : <My Color Here>, NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, NSFontAttributeName : font};
[backButton setTitleTextAttributes:dictionary forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

This seems like a really really bad way to go. Is there a bug in Inherited in Storyboard or something? I will try to learn more.